# How to get username from client id after the user has left the guild

Tags: discord, discord.js

I have statistics. I am downloading from the User Id database and I am replacing the ID with its name, but if the user has left the server, there is an error because there is no such user.

I have `bot.users.get(id)` but when a user leaves the server, an error pops up.

Can I get the username with the ID differently if the user is not on the server?

Comment: How do you plan on getting the id if the user is not on the server anymore. Input?

Comment: How i can check that user id is on the server?

Answer (score 4):

Sorry for being late, like literally. You can perform a request to get a user from Discord by a `UserResolvable` with `Client#fetchUser(<UserResolvable>);`.

In practice, the code should look like this;

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const Client  = new Discord.Client();

Client.login("YoUr.nIcE.toKe.n");

Client.on("ready", function () { // Should do that when the client is ready.
    const User = Client.fetchUser("123456789012345678");
    console.log(User); // Some user object.
});
```

Hope I helped you nonetheless.
~Q

Answer (score 2):

Since [`client.users`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=users) stores only cached users, you won't be able to retrieve their username in a reliable way from there.

**DISCLAIMER**: This method is **really** inefficient, but discord.js hasn't been made for this kind of work. If you want to make it easier, just write `Unknown user (client_id)`

If you're not able to get the username from a user list you could try to use messages: use [`channel.fetchMessages()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=fetchMessages) on every channel of your guild until you find a message in which `message.author.id == your_id`, when you find it you can get the username with `message.author.username`

There's also another solution: a *self-bot*. Keep in mind that this one is not supported by Discord itself, and could result in [a permanent ban for the account you're using](https://support.discordapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002192352-Automated-user-accounts-self-bots-).
With that said, if you use a self-bot you can use the [`TextChannel.search()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=search) method to quickly find a message with your author id and then grab the username from the author.

Comment: Please help. How i can check that user id is on the server? Now if user isnt on server - bot crash.

message.guild.members.get(rows[4]['userID']).user.username

Comment: Read my answer: your method won't work because there's no such member in your guild.

Comment: But how i can check that user id is on the server, because i want replace to e.g "This user isnt on this server!"

Comment: If `guild.members.get("user_id_here")` returns `undefined` then the user is not in the guild anymore.